# IntelliJ IDEA v2019.2 Indent Pulling Values Before Equal Sign Across Line

Tags: intellij-idea

If we take a line with an assignment value -

```
test = ${var.domain}
```

And then put the cursor before the equals sign and press the tab button, rather than tabbing the equals sign across the line, it pulls "test" with it across the line.

What is the fix for this?

## Here is a copy of the startup log

I'm unable to see anything obvious in the log.

```
2019-10-10 14:10:25,899 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,036 [    137]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: IntelliJ IDEA (build #IC-192.5728.98, 23 Jul 2019 07:11) 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,106 [    207]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows Server 2016 (10.0, amd64) 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,106 [    207]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 (JetBrains s.r.o) 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,106 [    207]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,112 [    213]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf -Djb.vmOptionsFile=D:\Users\Me\.IdeaIC2019.2\config\idea64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2\jbr\\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2\jbr\\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=Idea -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2019.2 -XX:ErrorFile=D:\Users\Me\java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=D:\Users\Me\java_error_in_idea.hprof 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,113 [    214]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - charsets: JNU=Cp1252 file=Cp1252 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,167 [    268]   INFO - tellij.diagnostic.LoadingPhase - Reached SPLASH loading phase 
2019-10-10 14:10:26,237 [    338]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - CPU cores: 2; ForkJoinPool.commonPool: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@3bb746f4[Running, parallelism = 2, size = 0, active = 0, running = 0, steals = 0, tasks = 0, submissions = 0]; factory: com.intellij.concurrency.IdeaForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory@3966e951 
2019-10-10 14:10:27,618 [   1719]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-groovy.xml 
2019-10-10 14:10:27,619 [   1720]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor duplicates-detection-groovy.xml 
2019-10-10 14:10:28,365 [   2466]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Cannot find optional descriptor profiler-java.xml 
2019-10-10 14:10:28,524 [   2625]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 2503 ms 
2019-10-10 14:10:28,527 [   2628]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2019-10-10 14:10:28,818 [   2919]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded bundled plugins: Android Support (10.3.3), Ant (192.5728.98), Bytecode Viewer (192.5728.98), ChangeReminder (192.5728.98), Configuration Script (192.5728.98), Copyright (192.5728.98), Coverage (192.5728.98), Eclipse Interoperability (192.5728.98), EditorConfig (192.5728.98), Git (192.5728.98), GitHub (192.5728.98), Gradle (192.5728.98), Gradle-Maven (192.5728.98), Groovy (192.5728.98), IDEA CORE (192.5728.98), IntelliLang (192.5728.98), JUnit (192.5728.98), Java (192.5728.98), Java Bytecode Decompiler (192.5728.98), Java IDE Customization (192.5728.98), Java Internationalization (192.5728.98), Java Stream Debugger (192.5728.98), JavaFX (192.5728.98), Kotlin (1.3.41-release-IJ2019.2-1), Markdown (192.5728.98), Maven (192.5728.98), Mercurial (192.5728.98), Plugin DevKit (192.5728.98), Properties (192.5728.98), Settings Repository (192.5728.98), Shell Script (192.5728.98), Smali Support (192.5728.98), Subversion (192.5728.98), Task Management (192.5728.98), Terminal (192.5728.98), TestNG (192.5728.98), TextMate bundles (192.5728.98), UI Designer (192.5728.98), XPathView + XSLT (192.5728.98), XSLT Debugger (192.5728.98), YAML (192.5728.98) 
2019-10-10 14:10:28,818 [   2919]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Loaded custom plugins: ANSI Highlighter (1.2.4), AWS Toolkit (1.6), Catdea (1.1.2), HashiCorp Terraform / HCL language support (0.7.7) 
2019-10-10 14:10:31,249 [   5350]   INFO - tellij.diagnostic.LoadingPhase - Reached CONFIGURATION_STORE_INITIALIZED loading phase 
2019-10-10 14:10:31,354 [   5455]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=713 
2019-10-10 14:10:31,769 [   5870]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Starting file watcher: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2\bin\fsnotifier64.exe 
2019-10-10 14:10:31,849 [   5950]   INFO - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Native file watcher is operational. 
2019-10-10 14:10:34,937 [   9038]   INFO - til.net.ssl.CertificateManager - Default SSL context initialized 
2019-10-10 14:10:34,999 [   9100]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2019-10-10 14:10:35,693 [   9794]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - File index extensions iterated:189 
2019-10-10 14:10:36,944 [  11045]   INFO - ts.jetbrains.core.AwsSdkClient - Create new Apache client 
2019-10-10 14:10:38,104 [  12205]   INFO - pl$FileIndexDataInitialization - Initialization done:2600 
2019-10-10 14:10:38,505 [  12606]   INFO - exImpl$StubIndexInitialization - Initialization done:400 
2019-10-10 14:10:38,523 [  12624]   INFO - tellij.diagnostic.LoadingPhase - Reached FRAME_SHOWN loading phase 
2019-10-10 14:10:38,866 [  12967]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 879 ms spent to cache options in application 
2019-10-10 14:10:41,997 [  16098]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [Git] - [D:/Users/Me/Documents/ide-my-lab]
2019-10-10 14:10:42,856 [  16957]   INFO - com.intellij.ide.ui.UISettings - Loaded: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0; restored: fontSize=13, fontScale=1.0 
2019-10-10 14:10:44,413 [  18514]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2019-10-10 14:10:48,394 [  22495]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 1292ms; general responsiveness: 1/1 sluggish; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-10-10 14:10:49,010 [  23111]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 590ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 0/1 sluggish, 1/1 very slow 
2019-10-10 14:10:49,011 [  23112]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 8 files to update 
2019-10-10 14:10:52,500 [  26601]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 3489ms; general responsiveness: 2/4 sluggish; EDT responsiveness: 1/2 sluggish, 1/2 very slow 
2019-10-10 14:10:53,521 [  27622]   INFO - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - LONG VFS PROCESSING. Topic=NewVirtualFileSystem changes, offender=class com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.PsiVFSListener$2, message=after, time=129ms 
2019-10-10 14:10:55,211 [  29312]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Load external projects data in 11 millis (read time: 0) 
2019-10-10 14:10:55,481 [  29582]   WARN - com.intellij.util.xmlb.Binding - no accessors for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinDefaultHighlightingSettingsProvider 
2019-10-10 14:10:57,201 [  31302]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 4033 ms spent to cache options in project 
2019-10-10 14:10:57,600 [  31701]   INFO - ntials.profiles.ProfileWatcher - Watching D:\Users\Me\.aws for file changes 
2019-10-10 14:10:57,601 [  31702]   INFO - ntials.profiles.ProfileWatcher - Watching D:\Users\Me\.aws for file changes 
2019-10-10 14:10:58,743 [  32844]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Some post-startup activities freeze UI for noticeable time. Please consider making them DumbAware to run them in background under modal progress, or just making them faster to speed up project opening. 
2019-10-10 14:10:58,863 [  32964]   WARN - lkitCredentialsProviderFactory - Failed to load AWS profiles 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Profile 'default' is missing required property aws_access_key_id
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider$requiredProperty$2.get(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.kt:215)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider$requiredProperty$2.get(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.kt:43)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.requiredProperty(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.kt:214)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.requiredProperty$default(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.kt:209)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.createInternalCredentialProvider(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.kt:135)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.<init>(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProvider.kt:50)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory$loadFromProfileFile$$inlined$map$lambda$1.invoke(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory.kt:77)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory$loadFromProfileFile$$inlined$map$lambda$1.invoke(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory.kt:23)
    at software.aws.toolkits.core.utils.LogUtilsKt.tryOrThrowNullable(LogUtils.kt:44)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory.loadFromProfileFile(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory.kt:70)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory.<init>(ProfileToolkitCredentialsProviderFactory.kt:32)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileCredentialProviderFactory.createToolkitCredentialProviderFactory(ProfileCredentialProviderFactory.kt:14)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.profiles.ProfileCredentialProviderFactory.createToolkitCredentialProviderFactory(ProfileCredentialProviderFactory.kt:13)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.ExtensionPointCredentialsProviderRegistry.listFactories(ExtensionPointCredentialsProviderRegistry.kt:44)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.ExtensionPointCredentialsProviderRegistry.listFactories(ExtensionPointCredentialsProviderRegistry.kt:37)
    at software.aws.toolkits.core.credentials.DefaultToolkitCredentialsProviderManager.reloadFactories(ToolkitCredentialsProviderManager.kt:85)
    at software.aws.toolkits.core.credentials.DefaultToolkitCredentialsProviderManager.<init>(ToolkitCredentialsProviderManager.kt:42)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.DefaultCredentialManager.<init>(CredentialManager.kt:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:88)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceManagerImpl.java:243)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.lambda$getComponentInstance$0(ServiceManagerImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:192)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:231)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:44)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.CredentialManager$Companion.getInstance(CredentialManager.kt:27)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.DefaultProjectAccountSettingsManager.<init>(ProjectAccountSettingsManager.kt:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:88)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.createAndInitialize(ServiceManagerImpl.java:243)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.lambda$getComponentInstance$0(ServiceManagerImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:197)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:231)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:49)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.credentials.ProjectAccountSettingsManager$Companion.getInstance(ProjectAccountSettingsManager.kt:103)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.AwsSettingsPanel.<init>(AwsSettingsPanel.kt:53)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.core.AwsSettingsPanelInstaller.runActivity(AwsSettingsPanel.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivity(StartupManagerImpl.java:205)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions$2(StartupManagerImpl.java:172)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointImpl.java:321)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointName.java:140)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions(StartupManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$null$8(ProjectManagerImpl.java:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.loadProjectUnderProgress(ProjectManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$openProject$9(ProjectManagerImpl.java:394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.openProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:439)
    at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.prepareAndOpenProject(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:272)
    at com.intellij.platform.PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.lambda$doOpenProject$0(PlatformProjectOpenProcessor.java:198)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$9(ApplicationImpl.java:552)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-10-10 14:10:58,897 [  32998]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 12332ms; general responsiveness: 5/12 sluggish; EDT responsiveness: 4/12 sluggish, 7/12 very slow 
2019-10-10 14:11:00,335 [  34436]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - D:/Users/Me/Documents/ide-my-lab/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false
2019-10-10 14:11:00,395 [  34496]   INFO - tellij.diagnostic.LoadingPhase - Reached PROJECT_OPENED loading phase 
2019-10-10 14:11:00,414 [  34515]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - [.] git version 
2019-10-10 14:11:01,674 [  35775]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - git version 2.21.0.windows.1 
2019-10-10 14:11:01,936 [  36037]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 21731 ms 
2019-10-10 14:11:02,169 [  36270]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-10-10 14:11:02,969 [  37070]   INFO - ea.config.GitExecutableManager - Git version for C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe : 2.21.0 
2019-10-10 14:11:02,992 [  37093]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 2 
2019-10-10 14:11:04,666 [  38767]   INFO - s.roots.VcsRootProblemNotifier - Auto-registered following mappings: [] 
2019-10-10 14:11:05,395 [  39496]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 311ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-10-10 14:11:05,609 [  39710]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 193ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-10-10 14:11:06,304 [  40405]   INFO - tellij.diagnostic.LoadingPhase - Reached INDEXING_FINISHED loading phase 
2019-10-10 14:11:07,611 [  41712]   WARN - gnostic.WindowsDefenderChecker - wmic Windows Defender check exited with status -2147217406: ERROR:
Description = Not found
 
2019-10-10 14:11:08,020 [  42121]   INFO - ings.impl.UpdateCheckerService - channel: release
2019-10-10 14:11:26,885 [  60986]   INFO -   #git4idea.log.GitLogProvider - Fresh repository: file://D:/Users/Me/Documents/ide-my-lab
2019-10-10 14:12:04,556 [  98657]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appCodeFoldingSettings took 49 ms, DiffSettings took 582 ms, FileTypeManager took 87 ms, TextMateSettings took 18 ms 
2019-10-10 14:12:06,781 [ 100882]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'D:\Users\Me\Documents\ide-my-lab' ide-my-labCompilerConfiguration took 13 ms
2019-10-10 14:12:06,782 [ 100883]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 3135 ms
```

Comment: Please share idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") after restarting IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this random issue was to reset the key mappings back to their defaults.

File > Settings > Keymap > choose the default from the dropline list for your OS. In my case it was "Default for Windows"

Happy coding!